# Is it posible to translate phone call from local language to English in node js

Tags: node.js, json, google-translate, google-translation-api, ws

I have tried for a long time trying to implement Google Media translate to translate a phone call in node js but it gave me error that I don't really understand how to fix them.

Here is my code:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
const path = require("path");

let stream = null;
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    //Call Initiated
      console.log("New Connection Initiated");
      ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
        const msg = JSON.parse(message);
        switch (msg.event) {
          case "connected":
            //Call connected
            console.log(`A new call has connected.`);

            const audio = require('@google-cloud/media-translation');
            const encoding = 'linear16';
            const sourceLanguage = 'sw';
            const targetLanguage = 'en-US';
            const sampleRateHertz = 8000;
            const model = 'google-provided-model/phone-call'
            const client = new audio.SpeechTranslationServiceClient;  
      
            const config = {
              audioConfig: {
                audioEncoding: encoding,
                sourceLanguageCode: sourceLanguage,
                sampleRateHertz : sampleRateHertz,
                targetLanguageCode: targetLanguage,
                targetModel : model
              },
              singleUtterance: false,
            };
            const initialRequest = {
              streamingConfig: config,
              audioContent: null,
            };
            let currentTranslation = '';
            let currentRecognition = '';
      
            stream = client
            .streamingTranslateSpeech()
            .on("error", console.error)
            .on('data', response => {
              const {result, speechEventType} = response;
              if (speechEventType === 'END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE') {
                console.log(`\nFinal translation: ${currentTranslation}`);
                console.log(`Final recognition result: ${currentRecognition}`);
                stream.destroy();
              } else {
                currentTranslation = result.textTranslationResult.translation;
                currentRecognition = result.recognitionResult;
                console.log(`\nPartial translation: ${currentTranslation}`);
                console.log(`Partial recognition result: ${currentRecognition}`);
              }
              // Send data to Google Media Translator
              let isFirst = true;
              msg.stream()
              .on('data', chunk => {
                if (isFirst) {
                  stream.write(initialRequest);
                  isFirst = false;
                }
                const request = {
                  streamingConfig: config,
                  audioContent: chunk.toString('base64'),
                };
                if (!stream.destroyed) {
                  stream.write(request);
                }
              })
              .on('close', () => {
                console.log("Stream Closed...")
              });
            });
             //Create Stream to the Google Speech to Text API
            break;
          case "start":
            console.log(`Starting Media Stream ${msg.streamSid}`);
            break;
          case "media":
            // Write Media Packets to the recognize stream
            stream.write(msg.media.payload);
            break;
          case "stop":
            console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
            break;
        }
      });  
    });
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening at Port 8080');
```

Now after I have run the code and call twilio phone number this is the error it generates

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: The first request must be a StreamingTranslateSpeechConfig request!
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/stanley/C-M-System/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/stanley/C-M-System/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:390:49)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/stanley/C-M-System/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at /home/stanley/C-M-System/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 3,
  details: 'The first request must be a StreamingTranslateSpeechConfig request!',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

I'm new to this web programming so if there is anyone who knows how to fix this and that can help me. I'm stacked at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-media-translation/blob/master/samples/translate_from_mic.js) And I found something different, maybe this is the issue.

Try and replace your const audio and const client with
´´´  // Imports the Cloud Media Translation client library
const {
SpeechTranslationServiceClient,
} = require('@google-cloud/media-translation');

// Creates a client
const client = new SpeechTranslationServiceClient();´´´

And let me know if it works please.

Comment: Thanks it is working. Thanks alot Jaime Lopez